# Best books for differential forms with geometric approach

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, differential-forms

I'm looking for a good book on differential forms with geometrical approach.

Could you kindly recommend some book??

Thanks advance

Comment: Are you looking for something diagrammatic? or just something that talks about the geometry?

Comment: Something that says about the geometric meaning.

Comment: Ok - Look up names like Do Carmo, Spivak, Boothby, Birkhauser, Loring Tu - Always good to have a selection to choose from. Just type in manifolds/differential forms into a search engine and it will pop up. You'll want to refresh yourself with manifolds, linear algebra and multivariable calculus to understand differential geometry effectively :)

Answer (score 1):

Introduction To General Relativity by Ryder Lewis.

A book for physics studies, but differential forms (in Ch.3.5) has been explained with geometrical approach much better than any other relevant maths books, I believe; at least is a great introductory one.

[Here](http://202.38.64.11/~jmy/documents/ebooks/Ryder%20Lewis%20%20Introductionto%20General%20Relativity.pdf) you can read it online.